# Optimizing C# code coverage collection and publishing in Azure DevOps Server 2020

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops, sonarqube, code-coverage

We use the following command line (more or less) to collect C# code coverage in our pipeline:

```
dotnet test --no-build -l trx -r TheResultsDir --collect "Code coverage" -s  CodeCoverage.runsettings
```

(We actually use the build-in `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task for that)

This produces a bunch of `.coverage` files. We want to do 2 things with them:

1. Send to our SonarQube server
2. Publish on the build itself using `PublishCodeCoverageResults@1` task.

As it turns out (surprise, surprise), the produced `.coverage` files are only understood by VS IDE.

As usual - Internet to the rescue. We figured out that:

1. Using the [Microsoft.CodeCoverage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeCoverage/) tool we can convert the `.coverage` files to `.xml` which are understood by SonarQube, but not the `PublishCodeCoverageResults@1` task.
2. Using the [reportgenerator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool) tool we can convert the `.xml` files from (1) to the Cobertura format understood by the `PublishCodeCoverageResults@1` task

And that is what we do and it is fine for small projects. However, now we introduce code coverage to our big monolithic application (sigh, helas - all is true) and the timings are awful. For one solution (out of several):

1. Conversion from `.coverage` to `.xml` takes about 20 minutes.
2. Conversion from `.xml` to Cobertura - 2h 33m.

So, this is really bad.

**Is there a better solution if I want both send to SQ and publish to the build?**

Here is the actual code we use:

**From `.coverage` to `.xml`**

```
CodeCoverage.exe analyze /output:CoverageResult.xml CoverageResult.coverage
```

(there are several `.coverage` files, so the command is applied on each one)

**From `.xml` to Cobertura**

```
reportgenerator.exe -reports:CoverageResults\*.xml -targetdir:CoberturaReport -reporttypes:Cobertura
```

**Publishing to build**

```
  - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
    displayName: Publish Coverage Results
    inputs:
      codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
      summaryFileLocation: CoberturaReport/Cobertura.xml
      failIfCoverageEmpty: true
```

Publishing to SonarQube is done with the standard SQ tasks:

1. Prepare SQ Analysis
2. Run SQ Analysis
3. Publish SQ Analysis

The prepare task is:

```
  - task: SonarQubePrepare@4
    displayName: Prepare CI SQ Analysis
    inputs:
      SonarQube: SonarQube
      scannerMode: MSBuild
      projectKey: $(SonarQubeProjectKey)
      projectName: $(SonarQubeProjectName)
      projectVersion: $(SonarQubeProjectVersion)
      extraProperties: |
        sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\vstest-coverage\*.xml
        sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths=$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\tests\*.TestResult.xml
        sonar.inclusions=**/*.cs
        sonar.branch.name=$(SonarQubeSourceBranch)
        sonar.scm.disabled=true
```

Comment: So your current concern is to make these two conversion tasks parallel, right? Or do you want to optimize the execution time of the two conversion tasks?

Comment: Parallel is useless. 20 minutes running in parallel with 2h 33m is still 2h 33m. I do not care how I do it if the end result - publishing to SQ and to the build does not take hours due to conversion from one format to another.

Comment: I could parallelize conversion to Cobertura with ALL the SQ related tasks - SQ analysis and SQ publish together take a lot of time too, but this complicates the build quite a lot. You need two build agents now and the resources are used heavily. Ideally I would like to find a way to eliminate the Cobertura conversion at all. If only it was possible to publish the **.coverage** files directly, that would be ideal.

Comment: I got it. This is closer to my guess. But it seems that there is no better way to directly publish the test results of type `.coverage` to the build

Answer (score 2):

> Ideally I would like to find a way to eliminate the Cobertura conversion at all. If only it was possible to publish the .coverage files directly, that would be ideal.

This is a [known issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/662921/code-coverage-report-display-blank.html) on Azure devops. Now, AFAIK, there is no such out box way to eliminate the Cobertura conversion. The only way is using the reportgenerator tool convert the the test result to the Cobertura format at this moment.

That because the Publish Code Coverage Results task only supports coverage result formats such as `Cobertura` and `JaCoCo`. And only support the download link for `.coverage` files currently.

Besides, this issue has been submitted in this earlier suggestion ticket linked here:

[support vstest .coverage "code coverage" build results tab](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/366142/support-vstest-coverage-code-coverage-build-result.html)

This feature request is **On Roadmap**, I believe it will be released soon, you can follow this thread to know its latest feedback.

Comment: TBH, this thread is not very encouraging, because it is said to sit for more than a year on the roadmap. Do you have any concrete information on what to expect?

Comment: Another alternative would be not to use the standard **Code Coverage** collector. Maybe you can advise an alternative collector that produces Cobertura right away? Or maybe reportgenerator can be invoked on the .coverage file rather than on XML? Because conversion from `.coverage` takes reasonable amount of time, but from XML to Cobertura is not.